# Como fazer o formato ":.0f" não arredondar meu número

Tags: python, python-3.x, print

Queria saber como uso o formato `":.0f"` sem ele arredondar o número.

Quero pegar um `input` de segundos e transformá-lo em minutos, aqui está meu código:

```
segundos = int(input())

minutos = segundos

while minutos > 60:
    temp = minutos / 60
    minutos = temp

print(f"Minutos: {minutos:.0f}")
```

Quero que ele imprima o número exato de minutos sem arredondar para que eu possa pegar o resto e colocar em segundos.

Porém quando eu entro com o `input` de 650 por exemplo, ao invés de me dar o valor 10 (minutos), ele me dá 11.

Eu sei que se eu colocar `.format(int(minutos))` ele irá me retornar o 10, mas teria algum jeito de especificar com algum argumento nesse `":.0f"` que eu não quero que ele arredonde? Como eu faço pra não ocorrer isto?

Comment: `print(f"Minutos: {minutos:.02f}")` ou sem nenhuma instrução de formatação com `print(f"Minutos: {minutos}")`

Comment: Só não esqueça que a quantidade depois do ponto nao é em "segundos" - 1.5 minutos == 1m:30s

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Na verdade você está tentando resolver o problema errado. Se quer que o resultado da divisão seja inteiro, use o [operador](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html?highlight=division#binary-arithmetic-operations) de divisão inteira `//` (duas barras em vez de uma).

Assim você não precisa se preocupar com arredondamento. E como você também disse que "*Quero que ele imprima o número exato de minutos sem arredondar para que eu possa pegar o resto e colocar em segundos.*", fazer a divisão exata também facilita para obter a quantidade de segundos restantes:

```
total_segundos = 650
minutos = total_segundos // 60
segundos = total_segundos - (minutos * 60)
# ou, nesse caso também poderia ser
# segundos = total_segundos % 60

print(f"{minutos} minutos e {segundos} segundos") # 10 minutos e 50 segundos
```

Como agora os resultados são inteiros (e não mais números de ponto flutuante), não é necessário especificar o formato (afinal, `.0f` diz para imprimir o número com zero casas decimais, e como os resultados já são números inteiros, especificar tal formato é desnecessário).

---

Nesse caso específico, outra opção para obter ambos os valores é usar [`divmod`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#divmod), que retorna uma tupla com o resultado da divisão inteira e o resto desta divisão:

```
total_segundos = 650
minutos, segundos = divmod(total_segundos, 60)
print(f"{minutos} minutos e {segundos} segundos") # 10 minutos e 50 segundos
```